# PyCharm (JetBrains) IDE - go to declaration on other split screen

Tags: python, ide, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

If i have split screen in JetBrain's pycharm IDE, can I Go To Declaration an object on one screen and have the resulting declaration appear on my other split screen? This would be very helpful in reading code without losing my place. I do realize you can go back to previous caret position as well but this would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is no direct way of doing this. The only option is a 3-step process where you press **Ctrl+B**/**Cmd+B** (on Mac) to get to the declaration and then right click on the new file and click the *Split Horizontally/Split Vertically* option (whichever you prefer).

This will open the selected file in splitscreen, next step is to select the initial file (PyCharm leaves your split file open in both columns by default) and you have both files open to look at.

Comment: That's unfortunate. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled across this question because I was looking for the same thing.
I have actually come up with a quick hack about this.
See if it works for you too.

## Configuration

`Settings...` > `Keymap` > `Split Vertically` > right click > `Add Abbreviation` > type `:vs` (which is the *Vim* shortcut for *Vertical Split*) > `OK`.

## Hack

I will assume you currently have one opened file and no splits.

- <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd> `:vs`
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> click definition

When you are done, go back to the starting point.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F4</kbd>(<kbd>F4</kbd>)